# Rev Slider Fatal Error in WordPress. Unable access dashboard

Tags: wordpress, uninstallation, fatal-error

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: [] operator not supported for strings in /homepages/46/d688139689/htdocs/dhruva/wp-content/plugins/revslider/inc_php/framework/base_admin.class.php:72 Stack trace: #0 /homepages/46/d688139689/htdocs/dhruva/wp-content/plugins/revslider/revslider_admin.php(157): UniteBaseAdminClassRev::addMetaBox('Revolution Slid...', Object(UniteSettingsAdvancedRev), Array, NULL) #1 /homepages/46/d688139689/htdocs/dhruva/wp-content/plugins/revslider/revslider_admin.php(68): RevSliderAdmin->addSliderMetaBox() #2 /homepages/46/d688139689/htdocs/dhruva/wp-content/plugins/revslider/revslider_admin.php(40): RevSliderAdmin->init() #3 /homepages/46/d688139689/htdocs/dhruva/wp-content/plugins/revslider/revslider.php(146): RevSliderAdmin->__construct('/homepages/46/d...') #4 /homepages/46/d688139689/htdocs/dhruva/wp-settings.php(215): include_once('/homepages/46/d...') #5 /homepages/46/d688139689/htdocs/dhruva/wp-config.php(89): require_once('/homepages/46/d...') #6 /homepages/46/d688139689/htdocs/dhruva/wp-load.php(37) in /homepages/46/d688139689/htdocs/dhruva/wp-content/plugins/revslider/inc_php/framework/base_admin.class.php on line 72

I renamed revslider folder name from FTP.  Still it's not working.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You can try to clear your cache when you disable the plugin.

What is your rev slider version?